# invalid spotipy redirect URL

Tags: spotipy

I have the error On Spotify I have generated a client ID and secret. With these I have a URL which I have set to be the redirect URL.

I am working with some spotipy sample code :

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    username = sys.argv[1]I
else:
    print "Whoops, need your username!"
    print "usage: python user_playlists.py [username]"
    sys.exit()
print("ClientID is", os.getenv("SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID"))
print("Prompting for token:")
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username)
```

The client ID shows as set correctly, but at the username prompt, I am taken to the website but have the error "Invalid Redirect URL".

Does this mean that :

1. I am using the wrong URL, or
2. I need to authorise that URL;
3. Some other thing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the format. You should have it start with the protocol. e.g. `http://localhost`.
If not, are you sure you registered your redirect_uri with Spotify?